# Is a compound index needed for querying on one field and using another for sorting?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In MongoDB, let's say I have the following query:

```
db.things.find({ name: 'some string' }).sort({ age: -1 })
```

I know that having an index for `age` will help performance, but do I create the indexes for `name` and `age` separately, or as a compound?

```
db.things.createIndex({ name: 1, age: -1 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a compound index.  Mongo DB's documentation goes into more detail here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

From that page:

> The following operations can use the index to get the sort order:
>
> ...
>
> db.data.find( { a: 5 } ).sort( { b: 1, c: 1 } ) -----------------------------------   { a: 1 , b: 1, c: 1 }